# Check if element count is odd, or else using CSS only

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to set layout dynamically by number of item, using display:flex, as below layout:

```
// If number of child element is odd, first item width is 100% else 50%
+---------+
|    1    |
+---------+
+---+ +---+
| 2 | | 3 |
+---+ +---+
+---+ +---+
| 4 | | 5 |
+---+ +---+
...
// If number of child element is even, all items width is 50%
+---+ +---+
| 1 | | 2 |
+---+ +---+
+---+ +---+
| 3 | | 4 |
+---+ +---+
...
```

The items example is as below:

```
<!-- Count : 1 -->
<div id="box">
    <div class="item">1</div>
</div>

<!-- Count : 2 -->
<div id="box">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
</div>

<!-- Count : 3 -->
<div id="box">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<!-- Count : 4 -->
<div id="box">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

So, I want to setup layout like below code, but I want to do it using CSS only.

```
function setLayout() {
    if (items.length % 2 === 0) {
        // Even
        // ... All items width set to 50%
    }
    else {
        // Odd
        // ... First item width set to 100%
        // ... All items width set to 50%, except first item
    }
}
```

I refer the document, but I don't know how to "count" items and apply CSS for count condition(if odd/even).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#tree-structural_pseudo-classes

So, how can I gets number of items is odd or even, and apply different setting, using CSS only?

Comment: CSS is declarative so values are derived initially by the programmer -- essentially we tell CSS **what** we want done -- a real language such as JavaScript we instruct **how** we want something done. So you want to **count** a certian amount of tags then **depending** on the results you want to **do** something. There isn't any `if`s in CSS. Dynamic behavior is very limited and circumstances are very specific. And the flow  of tags interacting with other tags are generally casscading (form-controls are the exception more so than others).

Comment: I just thought of how to count accurately but it isn't very flexible. If it's `flexbox` you can manually assign `order` property.

Comment: @zer00ne we can have some logic with CSS including this particular case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
#box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  border:5px solid blue;
  margin:10px;
}

#box > div {
  flex: 40%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

/* select the first element of it's an "odd" child counting from the end */
#box > div:first-child:nth-last-child(odd) {
  flex-basis:100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Count : 1 -->
<div id="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
</div>

<!-- Count : 2 -->
<div id="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
</div>

<!-- Count : 3 -->
<div id="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<!-- Count : 4 -->
<div id="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->

<!-- Count : 5 -->
<div id="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css. but before that remember one `id` can only be applied to one element (ids cannot be repeated). what you can do is add `class="box"` to the divs and use `:nth-child()` as below code

```
.box .item:nth-child(1){
 // your code
}


.box .item:nth-child(odd){
 // your code for elements 1,3,etc
}

.box .item:nth-child(even){
 // your code for elements 2,4,etc
}
```

***Edit:***

You can create 2 classes called `count-odd` and `count-even` add your desired styles to them and use below js code to add classes dynamically, as given in below snippet

```js
function setCountClass() {
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box"); 
  boxes.forEach((e, i) => {
    if (e.children.length % 2 === 0) {
      e.classList.add("count-even");
    } else {
      e.classList.add("count-odd");
    }
  });
}

setCountClass();
```

```css
.box{
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.count-even{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.count-odd{
  background: blue; 
  color: white;
}

.count-odd div:first-child{
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!-- Count : 1 -->
<div class="box">
    <div class="item">1</div>
</div>

<!-- Count : 2 -->
<div class="box">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
</div>

<!-- Count : 3 -->
<div class="box">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<!-- Count : 4 -->
<div class="box">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the "nth-child(1)" is ignored because of "nth-child(odd)", and always first item applyed "odd" condition.

First item style should be determined by number of total items is even or odd.

Comment: I have eidted the answer for why u needed. hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I checked your edited code. but I don't want to use any JavaScript code as I mentioned.  That's why the problem is difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need only to check if the count of whole elements odd or even. Then you can assign byusing Javascript a class to the wrapped box element.
Two working examples. One with odd and one with even elments.

**Odd Elements**

```js
const elements = 5;
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
let className = (elements % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';

for (let i = 0; i < elements; i++) {  
  let item = document.createElement('div')
  item.setAttribute('class','item');
  item.innerHTML = (i + 1);
  box.append(item);  
}
console.log(className)
box.classList.add(className);
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #e2eaf4;
  padding: 10px; 
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 40%;  
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background: #3794fe;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 12px;  
}


.odd .item:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

**Even Elements**

```js
const elements = 4;
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
let className = (elements % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';

for (let i = 0; i < elements; i++) {  
  let item = document.createElement('div')
  item.setAttribute('class','item');
  item.innerHTML = (i + 1);
  box.append(item);  
}
console.log(className)
box.classList.add(className);
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #e2eaf4;
  padding: 10px; 
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 40%;  
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background: #3794fe;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 12px;  
}


.odd .item:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to use any javascript code. If I can use javascript, it is really easy question.

Comment: @Park I understood and read it in your question. I was not aware until today that you can use the pseudo element in a chain. That's why I used JS in my solution to assign a corresponding class in a specific case. But with TemaniAfif  answer (`div:first-child:nth-last-child(odd)`) I learned something new today. Thanks for that :-) ! And I also found your question exciting. Because it is very practical.